# NLog Delete oldest file when Archive reaches certain Size (100MB)

Tags: .net, windows-services, nlog

How can i configure NLog the way that as soon as the Archive Reaches 100MB the oldest file gets deleted?

Comment: You can combine `archiveAboveSize` and `maxArchiveFiles` in order to achieve that

Comment: @Kahbazi Thank you. I have done that till now. But i was wondering if there was a better solution to this.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archival-options) is the documentation for archive options in case you missed it

Comment: @Dinch yeah i saw that. But there is no option to limit the _maxArchiveSize_ , but as @Kahbazi stated. The only option is to compbine `archiveAboveSize` and `maxArchiveFiles`

Comment: Since NLog doesn't exactly have support what you need, have you considered different approaches. Maybe creating a script, or basic console app, and add as 
a scheduled task.

Comment: I studied NLog source. It cannot be done within NLog itself. It does not provide this feature, and it's not extendable in that way. You have to do it manually.